# How to add custom soap headers in wcf?

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

Can I add Custom SOAP header in WCF incoming/outgoing messages in basicHttpBinding, like we can add custom authentication header in ASMX web services? Those custom SOAP header should be accessible using .net 2.0/1.1 web service clients (accessible by WSDL.EXE tool) .

Comment: updated my answer with info about message inspectors

Comment: updated my answer again with info on ASMX/WCF interoperability with regard to SOAP headesr

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Check out the [WCF Extras](http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex - it's an easy extension library for WCF which offers - among other things - custom SOAP headers.

Another option is to use [WCF message contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx) in your WCF service - this also easily allows you to define and set WCF SOAP headers.

```
[MessageContract]
public class BankingTransaction
{
  [MessageHeader]
  public Operation operation;
  [MessageHeader] 
  public DateTime transactionDate;

  [MessageBodyMember] 
  private Account sourceAccount;
  [MessageBodyMember] 
  private Account targetAccount;
  [MessageBodyMember] 
  public int amount;
}
```

Here, the "operation" and the "transactionDate" are defined as SOAP headers.

If none of those methods help, then you should check out the concept of WCF Message Inspectors which you can write as extensions. They allow you to e.g. inject certain headers into the message on every outgoing call on the client, and retrieving those from the message on the server for your use.

See this blog post [Handling custom SOAP headers via WCF Behaviors](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2008/02/25/handling-custom-soap-headers-via-wcf-behaviors.aspx) for a starting point on how to write a message inspector, and how to include it in your project setup.

The client side `IClientMessageInspector` defines two methods `BeforeSendRequest` and `AfterReceiveReply` while the server side `IDispatchMessageInspector` has the opposite methods, i.e. `AfterReceiveRequest` and `BeforeSendReply`.

With this, you could add headers to every message going across the wire (or selectively only to a few).

Here's a snippet from a `IClientMessageInspector` implementor we use to automagically transmit the locale information (language and culture info) across from the clients to the server - should give you an idea how to get started:

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{
    International intlHeader = new International();
    intlHeader.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;

    MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader(WSI18N.ElementNames.International, WSI18N.NamespaceURI, intlHeader);
    request.Headers.Add(header);

    return null;
}
```

On the server side, you'd then check for the presence of those headers, and if present, extract them from the SOAP envelope and use them.

**UPDATE:** okay, you're clients are on .NET 2.0 and **not** using WCF - good news is, this should still work just fine - see this blog post [Custom SOAP Headers: WCF and ASMX](http://blogs.msdn.com/nathana/archive/2007/05/29/custom-soap-headers-wcf-and-asmx.aspx) for details. You could still use the message inspector on the server side to sniff and extract the custom headers being sent by your .NET 2.0 clients.

Comment: Thanks marc_s, I tried to us WCF Extras, I added "XmlSerializerFormat" attribute to Service Contract WCF Extras throw error while accessing Services. 
Is there any other solution available like WCF Extras? 
Can I add MessageContract as attribute to every methods as I added SoapHeader in ASMX services?
My Requirement is that I need to send the some (same say username & password ) data for every call to WCF service. 
Is there any way to implement this one?

Comment: yah marc_s,  that looks great. but in the article mentioned the client should be in .net 3.0 or higher..but in my case, clients are in .net 2.0 & 1.1. Is it still possible to implement this one?

Answer (score 4):

This solution was simpler for me:

```
            var client = "Your Service Client"; 
            using (var scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
            {
                System.Xml.XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
                XmlElement element = document.CreateElement("wsse", "UsernameToken", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");

                XmlElement newChild = null;
                newChild = document.CreateElement("wsse", "Username", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
                newChild.InnerText = "finance";
                element.AppendChild(newChild);

                newChild = document.CreateElement("wsse", "CorporationCode", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
                newChild.InnerText = "387";
                element.AppendChild(newChild);

                MessageHeader messageHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("UsernameToken", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", element, false);

                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(messageHeader);

                var result = client.GetCorporations(new CorporationType { pageNo = 1 });
            }
```