# Add Custom SOAP Header

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a WSDL that does not expose the SOAP headers, but I need to add the following in to the header:

```
   <soapenv:Header>
    <UsernameToken xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">ANONYMOUS</UsernameToken>
    <PasswordText xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">ANONYMOUS</PasswordText>
    <SessionType xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">None</SessionType>
   </soapenv:Header>
```

Is there anyway to do this in C# if these header values are not exposed?

Comment: You can do this using WCF, but not with ASMX.

Comment: Hello,
I have the same problem with Siebel and C# client.
Did you found the solution ?
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [MessageContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx) for control over Soap header/body

[How to add custom soap headers in wcf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976217/how-to-add-custom-soap-headers-in-wcf)